# How to install allegro 5 on Code::blocks windows

Tags: windows, installation, codeblocks, allegro

As in question how to do that I used a lot of guides and it never work could someone explain it to me step by step I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually made it work using this [wiki](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows_Vista,_Code%3a%3aBlocks_10.05_and_Allegro_5)